# Display lines from multiple .txt files (Python Script)

Tags: python, tkinter, display

I'm developing software on Python with tkinter.
My goal is to display the lines of a text file opened in my software.
No problem to display lines in tkinter I know how to do it.
Usually it's enough to open a single text file, so no problem I use this piece of script:

```
def OpenFiles(fichier_dir, display_lignes):

        global files
        mainframe = tk.Frame(bg='#1c2028')

        files = askopenfilenames(initialdir='C:/Users/%s/Desktop' % user,
                        filetypes =(("Text file", "*.txt"),("all files","*.*")),
                        title = "Open text file"
                        )

        fichier_dir['text'] = files
        lignes_count = sum(1 for _ in open(files))
        display_lignes['text'] = lignes_count
```

[Same code with explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCZUA.png)
(What's in red is tkinter, don't pay attention to it.)

Except this time I need to open multiple text files.
And the same code doesn't work, do you have any solutions?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is preventing you from opening multiple text files? Neither tkinter nor python itself limits you in any way to open multiple files.

Comment: No, that's not it at all.
I know very well how to open a file in python, I just want to display the number of lines.
I can display the lines from a single text file.
But I can't display the total number of lines of multiple open files.

Comment: Change `lignes_count = sum(1 for _ in open(files))` to `lignes_count = sum(len(open(f).readlines()) for f in files)`.

Comment: works perfectly, thank you very much.